# DX11: Drawing with index buffer not working?

Tags: c++, directx, directx11, index-buffer

For our student project I've been tinkering with an OBJ-loader in order to import models into our application.
It loads without issues, and drawing it *kind of* works without index (the model is obviously not represented correctly because I'm not using an index buffer)
However, drawing with `DeviceContext->DrawIndexed` shows nothing on screen.

[Without indexed drawing](https://gyazo.com/54258d87e3ee14d09272085a250f1206)

[With indexed drawing](https://gyazo.com/b986a695c16a9615ba3bcbbc6c4dcc31)

Buffer creation method:

```
void ObjectLoader::CreateBuffers()
{
    //Index buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC iBufferDesc;
    memset(&iBufferDesc, 0, sizeof(iBufferDesc));
    iBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    iBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    iBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA indexData;
    indexData.pSysMem = &ind;
    pDevice->CreateBuffer(&iBufferDesc, &indexData, &pIndexBuffer);


    //Vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    memset(&bufferDesc, 0, sizeof(bufferDesc));
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(TriangleVertex) * this->NumberOfVerts();

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    data.pSysMem = tva;
    pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &data, &pVertexBuffer);
}
```

Draw method:

```
void ObjectLoader::Draw()
{
    if (pDevice == nullptr)
        return;

    UINT32 vertexSize = sizeof(float) * 5;
    UINT32 offset = 0;

    pDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVertexBuffer, &vertexSize, &offset);
    pDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(this->pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    pDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    pDeviceContext->DrawIndexed(vIndex.size(),0 , 0);

    //pDeviceContext->Draw(this->NumberOfVerts(), 0);

}
```

Index data is initially stored in an unsigned integer array before being passed to `D3DD11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA`

```
//index array
UINT* ind;
```

What the hell am I missing? I've looked at several books on indexed drawing and it seems pretty straight-forward. At first I thought the winding order was reversed but I checked this by simply reversing the index array; same result.

If you need more code let me know, but I feel this should suffice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD);
```

This is only storing a single index.

Comment: Yep, shouldve double-checked that stuff.. Thank you!